# how to 'send_keys' to a textarea in python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, textarea, sendkeys

**Hey, im trying to 'send_keys' to a textarea in Instagram with *Python Selenium*, and im getting error:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Message...')]"}
```

**This is the element inspect:**

```
<textarea placeholder="Message..." class="" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
```

**and here is the code i wrote:**

```
    def message(self, user, message):
        self.nav_user(user)
        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Message')]")[0].click()
**# FROM HERE IM IN THE MESSENGER OF INSTAGRAM, TRYING TO 'send_keys'**
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Message...')]").click()     
   
   self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Message...')]").send_keys(message)
        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Send')]")[0].click()
```

Comment: Why don't you try to grab element with CSS selectors or class selectors?. Can you share more details like what website it is and how textarea tag looks like

Comment: this instagram. and unfortunately there is no tag.
<div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_        vwCYk                                        ItkAi                                                                       "><textarea placeholder="Message..." class="" style="height: 18px;"></textarea></div>

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: this is instagram messenger:
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/v2/493x308q90/r/922/QOLJwi.png

Comment: I think you need to put a wait for the textarea element Before you try to click it. Use an explicit wait.

Answer (score 0):

So actually adding time.sleep has worked for me. Thank You

```
self.nav_user(user)
        self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Message')]")[0].click()
        time.sleep(1)
        # if There is a Pop-Up windows to turn on notification we will use this line:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Not Now')]").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Message...')]").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[contains(@placeholder,'Message...')]").send_keys(message)
self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Send')]")[0].click()
```